# How to upgrade core-js@3 in react-native cli?

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-cli

I am trying to create new project with `react-native` cli, but when I create a new project I am receiving the following error message:

> react-native > create-react-class > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.

Listed below is the contents of my `package.json` file:

```
{
      "name": "EmojiDictRN",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.8.3",
        "react-native": "0.59.8"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
        "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      }
    }
```

To see the full output from my terminal please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt7BM.png). Any ideas on how to resolve this warning message?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download and save the version of the `core-js` module which is requested within your warning message:

```
npm install --save core-js@^3
```

This will update the `core-js` dependency for your `react-native` project to use version `^3.x.x` which is still being actively maintained.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Can you please guide how to do it globally because this command will only do it in the current project.