# Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface

I get the following error when executing the command "ng new projectname"

```
core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: It's not necessarily an _error_, it's just a warning message that indicates that version 2 of the `core-js` dependency is no longer maintained. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: @Edric Thank you for your response. It seems like when I run the angular application, I get another template than normally, where did this change come from? Normally I would see a particular template after doing ng start --open, but now I see another template. Why is that?

Comment: Wdym? If you're facing another problem that is not related to this question, please consider asking another question regarding the problem.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419458/9386929

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade core-js@3 in react-native cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419415/how-to-upgrade-core-js3-in-react-native-cli)

Comment: I had the same issue and solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354180/error-please-upgrade-your-dependencies-to-the-actual-version-of-core-js3?noredirect=1) helped me.