# Error: Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to run `npm start` but giving me error "An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" I also tried to install it by using `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular` but still getting me an error.

> Error "npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer
> maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues.
> Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3."

How can I upgrade my dependencies?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should be able to simply update the version of the core-js module that is requested within the warning message:

```
npm install --save core-js@^3
```

For what it's worth npm has a nifty feature that lets you see which packages are [outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated)

```
npm outdated
```

You can also update packages to the latest versions using the [update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) command

Comment: Thank you. Just need some time installing `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Answer (score 14):

Below steps solved the issue for me,

```
npm i --package-lock-only
npm audit fix
```

**--package-lock-only** This will determine versions of packages to install using package.json, and then create a package-lock.json file with its resolved versions if none exists, or overwrite an existing one.

**audit fix** Scan your project for vulnerabilities and automatically install any compatible updates to vulnerable dependencies

[More Information Here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-audit)

Comment: Good, but what are those lines doing?

Answer (score 6):

you can run **'npm audit fix'**, which will update the dependencies that are causing update and version errors

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with the outdated dependency. I performed the following steps and it worked for me:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm outdated (to check all the outdated dependency)

npm update
```

Finally go to the folder containing your project, then run this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: why it's required to run `@angular/cli` global install inside the project folder?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me

```
$ npm ci
```

Comment: you could maybe specify what this command does

Comment: Can you explain not just throw a line of code?

Answer (score 0):

This solved issue for me,

first delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file
then in your package.json file change core-js version to ^3
then run "npm install --legacy-peer-deps"
after this try running your project