# npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues

Tags: angular, npm-install, core-js

I'm getting below error while creating a new Angular application -

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

I tried the solution given in below link but it did not work for me- [Error: Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354180/error-please-upgrade-your-dependencies-to-the-actual-version-of-core-js3)

When I check version of Angular using 'ng --version' command, I see `<error>` as version for below listed packages -

```
@angular-devkit/architect    
@angular-devkit/core         
@angular-devkit/schematics   
@schematics/angular          
@schematics/update
```

Could you please suggest what went wrong and what needs to be done to fix this?

P.S. - The same functionality was working fine a day before. And the already created projects are running fine locally.

Comment: Run command "npm outdated" inside your project directory. And see the difference between the Current And Wanted version of packages. And try to upgrade them to match wanted version.

Comment: with 'npm outdated' command inside project directory I got the list of packages to update/install. I did install/update these packages inside the project directory and then I could run the application successfully.
However, when I try to create a new project with 'ng new test-project', I get the same error.
How should I resolve this issue permanently?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19672#issuecomment-397323622 
 please refer to this thread

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya How come "core-js" doesn't show up when I run the command "npm outdated"? Output from the command listed some other modules. I updated them, but how would I ensure that core-js has been updated to resolve the original problem?

Answer (score 34):

Indeed the issue was with cache. `npm clean-install` worked.

Comment: didn't work on node v18

Answer (score 21):

It's a npm cache problem. Go to the path:

- Windows: `%AppData%/npm-cache`
- Linux/OSX: `~/.npm`

and delete its content. Then open your console in administrator mode and execute the `npm install` command again

Comment: This doesn't really work. Besides of the deprecated messages I also got an Error message, "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....1"

Answer (score 21):

Try:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: npm cache clean --force command throws an error : 
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'

Answer (score 18):

You should update the version of core-js to version above 3.

`npm install --save core-js@^3`

You may also update the outdated packages using 

`npm update [-g] [<pkg>...]`

Comment: I tried installing version 3 of core-js but it does not work.
I get below error - 

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\TypeScript_WorkSpace\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\TypeScript_WorkSpace\package.json'
npm WARN TypeScript_WorkSpace No description
npm WARN TypeScript_WorkSpace No repository field.
npm WARN TypeScript_WorkSpace No README data
npm WARN TypeScript_WorkSpace No license field.

If I run this command from inside the project directory, it works but when it comes to creating new project, it doesn't.

Comment: your second suggestion is a great start, but what I would add to your answer is **how do we detect which packages we using core-js@ to begin with**.  Once we know how to do that, then your 2nd line makes more sense to do as a final step.

Comment: @klewis You can identify which packages rely on core-js by running the command `npm ls core-js`. What's more, you can specifically identify v2 references by running `npm ls core-js@2`.

Answer (score 4):

I observed this warning message within a Vaadin project with Vaadin 14.1.3 after switching from dependency `com.vaadin.vaadin` to `com.vaadin.vaadin-core`.
The warning was gone after these steps:

1. delete `package-lock.json`
2. execute `mvn clean`
3. execute `mvn update`

Comment: where package-lock.json file is located?

Comment: In my case the package-lock.json is placed in the root of the Vaadin project. It's the same directory where package.json is placed and the same where (in case you use a Maven project) your pom.xml is placed.

Answer (score 2):

**So the issue is of version of the packages you have in your project.**

Run command `npm outdated` inside your project directory. And see the difference between the `Current` And `Wanted` version of packages.

And then upgrade all package to match wanted version.

Comment: The solutions given do work for a specific project but the issue is that the same problem occurs when I try to create any other new application.

Answer (score 0):

For **reactjs** project, update your react-scripts. Just
run `yarn add react-scripts@latest` or `npm install react-scripts@latest`.

This was what helped me after trying all the above commands

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out to be an issue with the node version. I downgraded from v16.0.0 to v14.17.1 and it was fixed.